# How can I route to a different page using Angular Routing?

Tags: angular, routes

I can't seem to find how to get to a specific page.

My destination is ./book-list.component.html managed by the component decorator below :

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-list',
  templateUrl: './book-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-list.component.css']
})
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

---

I trigger the event from goToBookList() home.component.html below :

```
<div class="activities btn-group-vertical">
    <a  class="btn btn-primary travels" href="#" role="button">Travels</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary books" role="button" (click)="goToBookList()">Books</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary restaurants" href="#" role="button">Restaurants</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary movies" href="#" role="button">Movies</a>
</div>
```

---

I implemented the method in the home.component.ts controller :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  goToBookList() : void {
    this.router.navigate(['/book-list']);
  }

}
```

---

I registered the route in my app-routing.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BookListComponent } from './themes/lists/book-list/book-list.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'book-list', component: BookListComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

---

I imported the AppRouting Module in the app.module :

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MessageModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MessageComponent, 
    LoginComponent,
    BookListComponent

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

**Important to note, i tried the routing with the router-outlet placeholder and the router-link directive and it works fine:**

```
<div class="activities btn-group-vertical">
    <a  class="btn btn-primary travels" href="#" role="button">Travels</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary books" role="button" [routerLink]="['/book-list']">Books</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary restaurants" href="#" role="button">Restaurants</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary movies" href="#" role="button">Movies</a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

It looks like the home.component.ts controller is not working fine.

```
  goToBookList() : void {
    this.router.navigate(['/book-list']);
  }
```

Any idea ?

It's my first time posting on here, I hope the post is understandable and concise; don't hesitate to give feedbacks !

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: What is happening when you click on Books? Is there any error in the console? Does the route change?

Comment: There is no error in console.
Yes, the route changes for : http://localhost:4200/book-list

Thanks !

Comment: Then are you sure the route is not loading? It seems like it is. Do you have anything in `book-list.component.html`? Add a `console.log('test');` in `ngOnInit` in `book-list.component.ts` to see if the component is being loaded.

Comment: Yes I have something in the .html.
I tried the console.log("test") in ngOnInit and there is nothing in the console. The controller is not loading and i don't understand why.





Here is the code of book-list.component.html :


`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  // selector: 'app-book-list',
  templateUrl: './book-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-list.component.css']
})
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("test");
  }

}`

Comment: Sorry about the code formating, not sure how it works in comments..

Comment: Are you sure you said that right? Is that is your `book-list.component.html`? That's typescript code, it should be `book-list.component.ts`. Your `book-list.component.html` should contain the html code.

Comment: Sorry, i made a typo. the code I pasted is from book-list.component.ts